# How to init an array of named tupples in swift

Tags: arrays, syntax, swift, namedtuple

I'm trying to create and array of named tuples. 
But when i'm calling the array constructor with the following line :

```
var test:[(test1:Int, test2:Int)] = [test1:Int, test2:Int](count: 12, repeatedValue: (test1:12, test2:12))
```

I get a compiler error. I've also tried :

```
var test:[(test1:Int, test2:Int)] = [Int, Int](count: 12, repeatedValue: (test1:12, test2:12))
var test:[(test1:Int, test2:Int)] = [Int,Int](count: 12, repeatedValue: (12, 12))
```

and i also get compilation error and i can't find the correct syntax to instantiate it properly.

What am-I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the extended array declaration:

```
var test = Array<(test1: Int, test2: Int)>(count: 12, repeatedValue: (test1:12, test2:12))
```

note that you do not need to specify the array type because type inferral takes care of that.

Alternatively, you can also define a type alias:

```
typealias tuple = (test1: Int, test2: Int)
var test = [tuple](count: 12, repeatedValue: (test1:12, test2:12))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i specified the type just because i wanted the question to be clear.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure you know :) See updated answer, there's also another way using `typealias`